# Running docker containers asynchronously with python

Tags: python, docker

I have moved our test framework into a docker container. One of my goals is to make it so we can spin up 1 container per test and then report he results.

I have this working with the following [please remember this is a WIP]:
api_test_runner.py

```
import subprocess
from api_test_list import single_test_list

for test in single_test_list:

    command = subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'run', '-e', 'USER=root', '-e', 'TEST=' + test, 'api_test_container'])
    print(command)
```

This runs through a list of tests and spins up a container for each one, but it waits for one container to stop before moving onto the next test:

```
(py3_api_automation) remmac05674:api_automation$ python api_test_runner.py
b'============================= test session starts ==============================\nplatform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.2.5, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.4.0\nrootdir: /app, inifile:\nplugins: xdist-1.20.1, forked-0.2, cloud-2.0.0\ncollected 1 item\n\ntest_1.py .\n\n=========================== 1 passed in 1.81 seconds ===========================\n'
b'============================= test session starts ==============================\nplatform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.2.5, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.4.0\nrootdir: /app, inifile:\nplugins: xdist-1.20.1, forked-0.2, cloud-2.0.0\ncollected 1 item\n\ntest_2.py .
```

What I am trying to sort out is how to have python run through the list of tests and kick off a container for each and not wait for other containers to finish.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I updated my script to use .Popen

```
for test in single_test_list:

    command = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '-e', 'USER=root', '-e', 'TEST=' + test, 'api_test_container'])
    print(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait for each, you will have to either run each 'docker run' command with -d (and write the output to a file) or fork every docker run on your test script independently